# Nginx config - rewrite both working and not woking

Tags: php, nginx

I am not proficient with Nginx, but I tried to setup a new web app basing on the configuration prepared by someone else on the same server.

I am trying to setup a rewrite so that /api/users request is redirected to /api/index.php. This statement under #API location is supposed to do the job:
`if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php; }`

But instead of being redirected to /api/index.php I get sent to index.html as defined in try_files under #PHP section.

Was my `rewrite` inside conditional statement executed at all?

If "Yes" then why I am getting redirected in #PHP section and not getting 404 from try_files under #API?

If "No" then why? And why the #PHP section was activated if $uri should not contain any '.php' part in that case.

Here is the main config:

```
server {
  server_name dev.app.myserver.com;
  listen 80;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.app.myserver.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/dev.app.myserver.com.error.log;

  # 
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  # Zmienne
  set $rootPath /data/dev-app/public_html;
  set $yiiDebug 1;
  set $editTranslations 1;

  # Ogolna konfiguracja
  include /data/dev-app/nginx/common/app.conf;
}
```

Plus the one included:

```
root $rootPath;
index index.html index.php;

# API
location /api {
  auth_basic          off;
  if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php; }
  # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

# PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  include fastcgi_params;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Any light on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: check what's in the logs. 500 is a generic serverside error.

Comment: Start by checking this file /var/log/nginx/dev.app.myserver.com.error.log. On linux, you might need sudo permissions to read it. If you still have questions, please post the contents of the error.log (make sure you only post relevant info).

Comment: error log says: [error] 30037#30037: *9076 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", (...), request: "GET /api/users HTTP/1.1", (...)

Comment: This question may have already been answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/505098/what-does-this-nginx-error-rewrite-or-internal-redirection-cycle-mean

Comment: maybe the `try_files` is improperly set (and I also tested with the one commented out) but what is wrong with `rewrite` in `location /api` that $uri is evaluated to invalid in `try_files`?

Comment: Does `/data/dev-app/public_html/index.php` exist?

Comment: That's a good call, Richard Smith! I see why I was getting 500 error. I still don't understand why my `rewrite` did not work and I ended up in try_files under PHP section.

Comment: I have rewritten the problem. My main question is whether `rewrite` in #API section is defined properly.